# Jupyter labでツールバーのアイコンが正常に表示されない

Tags: jupyter-lab

`python -m venv venv` で仮想環境を構築し、jupyter lab をインストールして開いたところ、
画像のように各種アイコンが表示されません。

この原因・問題解決方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

各種環境・バージョンは下記の通りです。

▼OS
Windows10

▼Pythonバージョン
Python 3.9.0

▼jupyter関連のバージョン
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.7
jupyter-console==6.2.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2

▼仮想環境のフルパス
F:\study\Jupyter\test\202011\venv

（ここで venv\Scripts\activate で仮想環境をactivatesし、
　jupyter labをpip install でインストール後、jupyter labを起動しています）

Comment: OSとPythonが同じ環境で試してみたら問題無くアイコン表示されました。ただしモジュールに`jupyter==1.0.0`というのは存在していなくて、類似してそうなのは`jupyterlab==2.2.9`が存在する状況ですが。起動したコマンドプロンプトの表示とか、`debug.log`といったファイルに何か情報は出ていませんか？

Comment: ご指摘いただいたjupyterlab==2.2.9 がインストールされていないことが原因ではないかと考え、今一度確認したところ、JupyterLabインストール時に、「pip install jupyter lab」と記述していました。。「pip install jupyterlab（スペースなし）」を実行し、jupyter labを起動したところ、正常にアイコンが表示されました。大変助かりました。早々にありがとうございました！

Comment: 経緯を自己回答してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

（自己確認結果）
Jupyter Labでアイコンが表示されなかった原因は、
コマンドプロンプトでJupyter Labをインストールする際の記述が誤っていたことが原因でした。
誤った記述：pip install jupyter lab
正しい記述：pip install jupyterlab

上記の正しい記述をすることにより、正常にJupyter Labがインストールされ、
Jupyter Labを起動すると、アイコンも正常に表示されました。